# Bash script to split a file by grep everything till the second time match in a column into one file and the rest into another

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to split a file with data like

```
  2   0.2345
 58   0.3608
 59   0.3504
 60   0.4175
 65   0.3995
 66   0.3972
 67   0.4411
411   0.3455
  2   1.3867
  3   1.4532
  4   1.2925
  5   1.2473
  6   1.2605
  7   1.2463
  8   1.1667
  9   1.1312
 10   1.1502
 11   1.1190
 12   1.0346
 13   1.0291
409   0.8025
410   0.8695
411   0.9154
```

For this kind of data, I am trying to split this into two files: 
File 1 : 2 -411 (first Column match) 
File 2 : 2-411 (second occurrence in the first column)

For this, I wrote these two one liners:

```
 awk '1;/411/{exit}' $1 > File1_$1 ;

 awk '/411/,0' $1 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' > File2_$1
```

The problem is that if there is a match of "411" (as in "67   0.4411") on the second column, my script prematurely cuts from that line.

I am unable to make the match on the first column only as occurrence of 411 on the second column can be number of times and not of interest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an idea could be to use this command combination

1. `awk '{ if ($1 >= 2 && $1 <= 411) print $0 }{if ($1=="411") exit}' input > f1`

then

2. `grep -v -f f1 input > f2`

if your input file is more bigger you should repeat step2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about Bash, but for regex i think you should indicate that the line begins with 411 like that *\b411*.